# How to extract time and store in an Array/Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to measure the time difference between two time readings in a Python script.

```
time_stamp_1 = datetime.datetime.now()
# some task
time_stamp_2 = datetime.datetime.now()

time_stamp = time_stamp_2 - time_stamp_1

time_stamp_sec = ??
```

I got the result as `0:00:04.052000`.

1. What exactly is this time format I am getting?
2. How to extract the time in seconds from `time_stamp`?
3. How to store `time_stamp` in an array like variable (as I want to use a loop and store the `time_stamp` for each loop)
4. How to store `time_stamp_sec` in an array like variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's a [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object which is being printed nicely:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(days=3)
datetime.timedelta(3)
>>> print(datetime.timedelta(days=3))
3 days, 0:00:00
>>> print(datetime.timedelta(hours=3))
3:00:00
```

2) You can use `total_seconds()`:

```
>>> t = datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
>>> t.total_seconds()
10800.0
```

This gives you a `float` as the `datetime.timedelta` may represent an amount of time which isn't an exact number of seconds.

3) You can append it to a list at each step in the loop:

```
>>> d = []
>>> d.append(t)
>>> d
[datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)]
```

4) You can do the same with the result of `total_seconds()`:

```
>>> e = []
>>> e.append(t.total_seconds())
>>> e
[10800.0]
```